# What is the translation of 'of it' in french?

Tags: grammaire

On top of it, at the bottom of it, the middle of it, the thought of it, all phrases that have stumped me.

Comment: Try https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/on+top+of+it.html, https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=at+the+bottom+of+it etc for some ideas of how to convey the idiom of it depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

"Of it" is not translated in some cases; in other cases it is replaced by a possessive, or sometimes by a demonstrative. In other cases yet, the pronoun can be replaced by the noun phrase that is its antecedent. The possibility of repacing it by a defining subordinate is not so rare.
What to do in which circumstances is a whole subject matter and I can't do much better without a lengthy study than listing a few examples illustrating the correspondence.

*not translated*

- There is a piece of furniture near the wall opposite  the door, you'll find the box **on top of it** (**at the bottom of it**, under the shelves).
  *Il y a un meuble près du mur opposé à la porte, vous trouverez la boite **dessus/au dessus** (**au fond**, sous les étagères).*
- Finally, the Internet which can itself be seen as a large and complex network, has enabled us to build on top of it various kinds of networks. ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LM-S2-JDf4wC&pg=PR5&dq=%22on+top+of+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB5_GqsebsAhVIxoUKHdH0DXsQ6AEwFnoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22on%20top%20of%20it%22&f=false))
  Finalement, l'internet, qui peut lui-même être considéré comme un réseau vaste et complexe, nous a donné la possibilité de greffer **dessus** des réseaux de sortes variées.
- On one side, very close to them, he could see Mrs. Walker's garden. She had placed a life-sized scarecrow in the middle of it to keep the ravenous birds away. ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kR0YdQB8vV8C&pg=PA46&dq=%22in+the+middle+of+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO2uuFtubsAhWL4IUKHbR2DSMQ6AEwBHoECFcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20middle%20of%20it%22&f=false))
  *Sur un côté, très près d'eux, il pouvait voir le jardin de madame Walker. Elle avait installé un épouvantail grandeur nature **au milieu** pour éloigner les oiseaux voraces.*

*not translated or replaced by noun phrase*

- His feet were not under the water but on top of it. ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gIT_2uMFxNQC&pg=PA119&dq=%22on+top+of+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB5_GqsebsAhVIxoUKHdH0DXsQ6AEwA3oECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22on%20top%20of%20it%22&f=false))
  *Ses pieds n'étaient pas sous l'eau mais **au dessus**.*
  *Ses pieds n'étaient pas sous l'eau mais **au dessus de l'eau**.*

*replaced by a possessive or not translated*

- There is a vast field and in **the middle of it** there is a spring.
  *Il y a un vaste champ et **en son milieu** se trouve une source.*
  *Il y a un vaste champ et **au milieu** se trouve une source.* (*same meaning*)

*replaced by a demonstrative*

- That was all there was to eat, a repugnant mash, and **the thought of it** recurred to her regularly.
  *C'était tout ce qu'il y avait à manger, une  pâtée répugnante, et **cette idée**  se rappelait à elle régulièrement.*

*replaced by a descriptive subordinate*

- As each object may come and go, be forgotten and then thought of again, it is held that **the thought of it** has a precisely similar independence, self-identity, and mobility. ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=TMrJfcaC8bYC&pg=PA196&dq=%22the+thought+of+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinkqvbu-bsAhUizIUKHY_4BsgQ6AEwAnoECFwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20thought%20of%20it%22&f=false))
  *Comme tout object peut apparaitre et disparaitre, être oublié et puis de nouveau être le sujet de la pensée, il est admis que **l'idée qu'on s'en fait** a une indépendance précisément similaire, sa propre identité et une mobilité.*